# Apple In-app Purchase and physical/digital goods

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I know that in-app purchase cannot be used to buy physical goods that are obviously not usable within an app.

But how the following case is treated?

I have an app which offers some free content (images, activities, etc) and others that are chargeable using in-app purchase. Here I have no problem.

But, what happens if part of the business model I have includes an annual subscription that gives members access to printed content as well as the digital one chargeable through IAP. That is, the membership makes you eligible for physical goods and free digital (previously chargeable) goods. No need for IAP anymore with this model.

How does Apple go about with this? Can I use external payment methods, given that physical goods are involved, or not?

Thanks for the help in advance
AF

Comment: I doubt Apple would complain if you just use Apple Pay instead.

Comment: But Apple Pay is for physical transactions, ie replacing card in shops etc. With the membership the user will receive printed material by post and will have log in details to use to log into the app and have access to the free content. Not sure Apple Pay work here?

Comment: I'd suggest you possibly email developer support and ask if using a 3d party (e.x. Paypal) would be acceptable here.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the question on Apple Developer Forums and got the following response. Hopefully it is useful for others

> "You may not use IAP for physical goods" does not mean "you may use non-IAP methods for digital goods when combined with physical goods".   The combination product cannot be sold using IAP nor may it be sold using IAP.  You will need to unbundle the two lines of business.

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/259973

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot access Apple Dev Forum topic. Can you plz share how you solved your issue? So is it impossible to offer digital features through non-IAP subscription?

Answer (score 0):

In-App Purchase will allow you to sell:

• Digital books or photos
• Additional game levels
• Access to a turn-by-turn map service
• Subscriptions to digital magazines or newsletters
• Digital content hosted on Apple servers

**Real-world services/Physical goods cannot be sold or purchased using IAP**

[In-App Purchase Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf)