# Apple IAP with discount on Physical Goods

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I know that IAPs can be used only to sell "digital" products.

But I want to offer a subscription in the app, that will both have new features available in the app (more photos that can be uploaded) and a discount on a physical book in my bookstore. 
Is it considered as a digital and physical product combination, or just a digital product?

Is that possible to do through Apple IAPs?

And if not, can you plz suggest a way to bypass the restriction?
If I switch to credit card subscription (using Stripe to handle it), wouldn't Apple ban my app for trying to sell both digital and physical product?

Thanks.

Also, in the most expensive plan, I want to offer free shipping of books for those who have the top subscription.

Among the questions that I've checked, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050296/apple-in-app-purchase-and-physical-digital-goods) seems close, but does not give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sell physical items through Apple's IAP. If your app provides services outside of the app itself, you can use your own payment processing within the app.

For instance, the Fandango app allows the user to purchase movie tickets through their app. Because of this, they are allowed to handle payment processing for buying movie tickets using their own mechanism instead of Apple's IAP.

I would suggest using Apple's IAP for digital purchases and a third party for physical sales.